# Two similar codes differ in speed in PyPy3

Tags: python, pypy

Here is a simplified code of nested loop and some if-conditions regarding index-access to a list.
I noticed that the second code (# In separate loops) works twice faster than the first one (# In the same loops) in PyPy3 (ver. 7.3.1).
Both run in the almost same speed in CPython (3.8.4rc1).

What is the factor making the second one faster?

```py
# In the same loop (slower)
import random

LIM = 10 ** 3


def main():
    random.seed(0)

    arr = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(LIM * LIM)]
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(LIM):
        for j in range(LIM):
            if arr[i]:
                cnt += 1
            if arr[i * 2]:
                cnt += 1
            if arr[j]:
                cnt += 1
            if arr[j * 2]:
                cnt += 1
            if arr[i + LIM]:
                cnt += 1
            if arr[j + LIM]:
                cnt += 1
            if arr[i * j]:
                cnt += 1
    print(cnt)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
# In separate loops (faster)
import random

LIM = 10 ** 3


def main():
    random.seed(0)

    arr = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(LIM * LIM)]
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(LIM):
        for j in range(LIM):
            if arr[i]:
                cnt += 1
    for i in range(LIM):
        for j in range(LIM):
            if arr[i * 2]:
                cnt += 1
    for i in range(LIM):
        for j in range(LIM):
            if arr[j]:
                cnt += 1
    for i in range(LIM):
        for j in range(LIM):
            if arr[j * 2]:
                cnt += 1
    for i in range(LIM):
        for j in range(LIM):
            if arr[i + LIM]:
                cnt += 1
    for i in range(LIM):
        for j in range(LIM):
            if arr[j + LIM]:
                cnt += 1
    for i in range(LIM):
        for j in range(LIM):
            if arr[i * j]:
                cnt += 1
    print(cnt)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I don't know if that's the cause, but the two programs do different things.  For example, the second program doesn't do `i // 2`.

Comment: I fixed the first one, yet the speed differs.

Comment: Likely that the second one can be optimized a lot because of the single condition in the loop

Comment: @MadPhysicist What else can be optimized in PyPy? I want to know the rules/tips to write a fast PyPy code.

Comment: @solzard. Isn't there documentation for that somewhere?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I skimmed the official document (https://doc.pypy.org/), but couldn't find the rule which conditions PyPy optimizes loop statements in.